# displaying a number in the following format '$454-25' in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I know how we can display a number like

> 00145248.25 as $145,248.25

using the method

```
TO_CHAR(00145248.25,'$999,999,999,999.99').
```

How can I display it using a '-' instead of a '.'?

Comment: after convert use replace to replace `.` with `-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using replace function to replace "." with "-".

```
REPLACE(TO_CHAR(00145248.25,'$999,999,999,999.99'),'.','-')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
REPLACE(to_char(00145248.25, '$99,999,999,999.00'),'.','-' )
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/7089)**